# R - Calculate average using time conditions and also other conditions on different column

Tags: r, time, aggregate, mean

I have a data with timestamp, category and the data value as shown below (but >2000 rows).

```
Timestamp   category    data  
7/16/2017 18:04 x   4.9  
7/16/2017 18:18 y   4.7  
7/16/2017 18:32 x   8.2  
7/16/2017 18:46 x   2.2  
7/16/2017 19:00 y   2.7  
7/16/2017 19:14 y   3.8  
7/16/2017 19:28 x   8.0  
7/16/2017 19:42 x   7.3  
7/16/2017 19:56 z   10.1  
7/16/2017 20:10 z   5.4  
7/16/2017 20:42 x   17.5  
7/16/2017 20:56 x   6.3  
7/16/2017 21:10 z   5.8  
7/16/2017 21:24 x   0.6  
7/16/2017 21:38 z   2.2  
7/16/2017 21:52 z   2.9  
7/16/2017 22:06 y   0.5  
7/16/2017 22:20 x   5.1  
7/16/2017 22:34 z   8.0  
7/16/2017 22:48 z   3.6
```

I want to calculate average and sd of my data by applying 2 conditions. The average and sd has to be calculated for every 2 hours. The average and the sd has to be seperately calculated for x,y,z categories.

The final data is supposed to look something like this

```
Timestamp   category    data_avg    data_sd  
7/16/2017 18:00 x         
7/16/2017 20:00 x         
7/16/2017 22:00 x         
7/17/2017 0:00  x 

Timestamp   category    data_avg    data_sd  
7/16/2017 18:00 y       
7/16/2017 20:00 y       
7/16/2017 22:00 y         
7/17/2017 0:00  y     

Timestamp   category    data_avg    data_sd  
7/16/2017 18:00 z         
7/16/2017 20:00 z         
7/16/2017 22:00 z         
7/17/2017 0:00  z
```

I tried filtering and aggregating using the following command

```
df<- aggregate(list(avgdata = df$data), 
                   list(hourofday = cut(df$Timestamp, "1 hour")), 
                   mean)
```

But its not working. It is missing so many data points and also it doesnt give mean and sd in same df.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Timestamp column is in a format, which is not easy to work with in R. Therefore I first turn it into a Datetime variable with `as.POSIXlt`.

```
df$Timestamp <- as.POSIXlt(df$Timestamp, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

head(df)
#             Timestamp category data
# 1 2017-07-16 18:04:00        x  4.9
# 2 2017-07-16 18:18:00        y  4.7
# 3 2017-07-16 18:32:00        x  8.2
# 4 2017-07-16 18:46:00        x  2.2
# 5 2017-07-16 19:00:00        y  2.7
# 6 2017-07-16 19:14:00        y  3.8
```

After this, the aggregate function works withe de appropriate arguments. I added category to the list of variables to group by and modified the `FUN` argument to calculate both `mean` and `sd`.

```
aggregate(list(avgdata = df$data), 
          list(hourofday = cut(df$Timestamp, "2 hour"), 
               category = df$category), 
          FUN = function(x) c(data_avg = mean(x), data_sd = length(x)))

#             hourofday category avgdata.data_avg avgdata.data_sd
# 1 2017-07-16 18:00:00        x         6.120000        5.000000
# 2 2017-07-16 20:00:00        x         8.133333        3.000000
# 3 2017-07-16 22:00:00        x         5.100000        1.000000
# 4 2017-07-16 18:00:00        y         3.733333        3.000000
# 5 2017-07-16 22:00:00        y         0.500000        1.000000
# 6 2017-07-16 18:00:00        z        10.100000        1.000000
# 7 2017-07-16 20:00:00        z         4.075000        4.000000
# 8 2017-07-16 22:00:00        z         5.800000        2.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your method works pretty good. But when i save it as another dataframe (df2 <- aggregate) it saves only the mean not the sd. The result has only 3 columns instead of 4. Any idea why? is there anyway to get the complete result using your code?

Comment: The 3rd column is actually a matrix column. 
If you use `do.call(data.frame, df2)` you'll get a data.frame with "simple" columns. 
You can check this with `str(df2)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df = structure(list(Timestamp = c("7/16/2017 18:04", "7/16/2017 18:18", 
"7/16/2017 18:32", "7/16/2017 18:46", "7/16/2017 19:00", "7/16/2017 19:14", 
"7/16/2017 19:28", "7/16/2017 19:42", "7/16/2017 19:56", "7/16/2017 20:10", 
"7/16/2017 20:42", "7/16/2017 20:56", "7/16/2017 21:10", "7/16/2017 21:24", 
"7/16/2017 21:38", "7/16/2017 21:52", "7/16/2017 22:06", "7/16/2017 22:20", 
"7/16/2017 22:34", "7/16/2017 22:48"), Category = c("x", "y", 
"x", "x", "y", "y", "x", "x", "z", "z", "x", "x", "z", "x", "z", 
"z", "y", "x", "z", "z"), data = c(4.9, 4.7, 8.2, 2.2, 2.7, 3.8, 
8, 7.3, 10.1, 5.4, 17.5, 6.3, 5.8, 0.6, 2.2, 2.9, 0.5, 5.1, 8, 
3.6)), .Names = c("Timestamp", "Category", "data"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))


df %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = mdy_hm(Timestamp),                   # update to a datetime variable (if needed)
         TimeDiff = difftime(Timestamp, min(Timestamp), units = "hours"),  # get the distance from the first timestamp of the dataset (in hours)
         TimeGroup = as.numeric(TimeDiff) %/% 2) %>%      # create a grouping variable based on the distance
  group_by(TimeGroup, Category) %>%                       # for each group and category
  summarise(Category_MinTime = min(Timestamp),            # get the first time stamp for this category in this group
            data_avg = mean(data),                        # get average
            data_sd = sd(data),                           # get sd
            NumObs = n()) %>%                             # get number of observations (might be useful)
  mutate(TimeGroup_MinTime = min(Category_MinTime)) %>%   # get first time stamp of that time group
  ungroup() %>%                                           # forget the grouping
  select(TimeGroup, TimeGroup_MinTime, everything())      # re arrange columns


# # A tibble: 8 x 7
#   TimeGroup   TimeGroup_MinTime Category    Category_MinTime  data_avg  data_sd NumObs
#       <dbl>              <dttm>    <chr>              <dttm>     <dbl>    <dbl>  <int>
# 1         0 2017-07-16 18:04:00        x 2017-07-16 18:04:00  6.120000 2.554799      5
# 2         0 2017-07-16 18:04:00        y 2017-07-16 18:18:00  3.733333 1.001665      3
# 3         0 2017-07-16 18:04:00        z 2017-07-16 19:56:00 10.100000      NaN      1
# 4         1 2017-07-16 20:10:00        x 2017-07-16 20:42:00  8.133333 8.597868      3
# 5         1 2017-07-16 20:10:00        z 2017-07-16 20:10:00  4.075000 1.791415      4
# 6         2 2017-07-16 22:06:00        x 2017-07-16 22:20:00  5.100000      NaN      1
# 7         2 2017-07-16 22:06:00        y 2017-07-16 22:06:00  0.500000      NaN      1
# 8         2 2017-07-16 22:06:00        z 2017-07-16 22:34:00  5.800000 3.111270      2
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I tried your method for my data. It said "Error: This function should not be called directly". Then I copied your whole script and tried again. Then also I got the same error. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Can't replicate this issue. You should try and run the piped commands step by step to see which function causes the issue. When you spot it we would be able to see what is the problem. :-) Looks like a `plyr` / `dplyr` conflict. Make sure you have `dplyr` package installed and maybe try to remove `plyr` package completely to see if it works...